# Word for having four sides or parts

Tags: vocabulary

I need a word to describe the arrangement of mammalian teeth, which is strictly speaking bilateral, but can also be thought of as having four quasi-homologous quadrants. "Quadrilateral" doesn't seem to be used this way by dentists according to a quick Google search, although they do use the word "quadrant."

> Thanks to the ***_*_** nature of dentition, we can have up to four
>   experimental groups per animal.

Comment: **quadripartite**

Comment: Yeah, I think Edwin nailed it. Note that this allows for different kinds of symmetry -- bilateral and vertical -- which is crucial for dentition -- while still basically referring to fourness and partness.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you! As a complete newbie, I don't have the privilege to vote for you yet, but I wish I could, many times.

Comment: Although it's somewhat less common than *quadripartite*, it seems to me [*tetrapartite*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tetrapartite%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is just as good.

Comment: "tetrahedral" -- a solid with 4 sides all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper answer, I believe, was provided by **Edwin Ashworth** in the comments:  quadripartite.  Since he has not posted this as an answer though, I am providing it here to allow for an accepted answer (especially given that the OP seems unable to upvote comments without further reputation)

> **Quadripartite**
>
> consisting of or divided into four parts

An alternative, provided by FumbleFingers was tetrapartite, which is an equivalent construction; but does not seem to have as many dictionaries to support it.

Comment: Personally I think John's comment re bilateral/vertical symmetry is central to OP's intended sense. I don't really understand why *bilateral symmetry* is used to mean "**one-way** symmetry" (one of the two contradictory meanings of [bisymmetric](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bisymmetric)). But personally I'd be more likely to say mammalian dentition often exhibits ***two-way symmetry*** (though obviously not *always*, when you consider things like beavers and walruses! :)

Comment: Mammalian teeth are typically only bilaterally symmetrical.  The top and bottom aren't symmetric (this is true for most mammals, including dogs, cats, horses, humans, etc).  The OP specifies they are quasi-homogoneous - similar but not actually symmetric.  In his example sentence, I'd likely say that "Thanks to the quadripartite quasi-homogoneous nature of dentition, we can have up to four experimental groups per animal".  I feel that trying to imply symmetry is not truly the point; only that the four quadrants are similar ENOUGH for multiple test samples per animal.

Comment: *Quasi-quadri-symmetry?* :) Personally I see *homogoneous* as being more concerned with things *made of the same stuff throughout, evenly-mixed*, rather than *similar in shape*.

Comment: lol.  I see your point though.  Perhaps a question should be asked tagged with one-word-request for "nearly symmetrical" or some such.

Comment: To be fair, OP used *quasi-homologous*. I'm only really familiar with *homologous* in the sense of "similar in many ways by virtue of origin". That's as distinct from *analogous* - "similar in some specific aspect of current interest, but usually *not* relating to origin". And I have just discovered that "repeated" biological structures (fern fronds, vertebrae, etc.) are [sometimes referenced using the term](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22homologous+vertebrae%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Answer (score 0):

**Quadrangular** could be used for four-sided:

> [Female teeth are considered more rounded and male teeth more
>   quadrangular](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21821163)

In the example above though, it's describing the shape of the tooth rather than distribution of teeth.

I don't really know enough about dentistry to say if it's suitable, but just another option to complement Edwin's *quadripartite*, seeing as you asked for four-sided also.